# Oracle query latest row with average for specific column?

Tags: sql, oracle, average, window-functions

Having the following dataset. I need some help with a sql statement that would give me the latest row based on `PING_DATE` with unique `PING_DESTINATION` and `PING_SOURCE` with added column with the `AVG` of `PING_AVG` for all rows within the last 10 minutes.

```
 PING_DATE            | PACKET_LOSS  | PING_MIN | PING_AVG | PING_MAX | PING_SOURCE | PING_DESTINATION
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 5/5/2015 12:58:18 PM |   0          |  68      |  68      |  72      |  site1      |  orange15
 5/5/2015 12:58:43 PM |   0          |  68      |  71      |  76      |  site1      |  orange15
 5/5/2015 12:59:11 PM |   0          |  68      |  68      |  72      |  site1      |  pear11
 5/5/2015  1:09:47 PM |   0          |  68      |  70      |  76      |  site1      |  pear11
 5/5/2015  1:43:59 PM |   0          |  68      |  69      |  72      |  site1      |  pear11
 5/5/2015  1:45:41 PM |   0          |  68      |  69      |  72      |  site1      |  pear11
 5/5/2015  2:03:43 PM |   0          |  68      |  68      |  72      |  site1      |  pear11
 5/5/2015  3:01:53 PM |   0          |  68      |  68      |  72      |  site1      |  pear11
 5/5/2015  3:02:05 PM |   0          |  68      |  69      |  72      |  site1      |  pear11
 5/5/2015  3:00:59 PM |  20          |  68      |  68      |  68      |  site1      |  pear11
 5/5/2015  3:01:07 PM |   0          |  68      |  68      |  72      |  site1      |  pear11
 5/5/2015  3:01:14 PM |   0          |  68      |  70      |  72      |  site1      |  pear11
 5/5/2015 12:46:55 PM |   3          |   3      |   3      |   3      |  site1      |  lemon1
```

Query Result:

```
 PING_DATE            | PACKET_LOSS  | PING_MIN | PING_AVG | PING_MAX | PING_SOURCE | PING_DESTINATION | 10minavg
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 5/5/2015 12:58:43 PM |   0          |  68      |  71      |  76      |  site1      |  orange15        |  71
 5/5/2015  3:01:14 PM |   0          |  68      |  70      |  72      |  site1      |    pear11        |  65
 5/5/2015 12:46:55 PM |   3          |  3       |   3      |   3      |  site1      |    lemon1        |   3
```

Comment: Give sample output... the question is not clear. Better make a table to show how the output should display

Comment: Group `site1, orange15` does not have 10-minutes average of `71` but of `69.5` (`(68+71)/2 = 69.5` ... or not?)

Comment: The same issue with group `site1, pear11` having 10-minute average of `(68+68+70+68+69)/5 = 68.6`. So, how exactly do you want your "last 10 minutes average" to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For "last 10 minutes average" being "last 10 minutes in each group" this is the query you are looking for:

```
with xyz as (
    select X.*,
        row_number() over (
            partition by ping_destination, ping_source
            order by ping_date desc
        ) as latest_row#,
        avg(ping_avg) over (
            partition by ping_destination, ping_source
            order by ping_date asc
                range between
                interval '10' minute preceding
                and current row
        ) as the_10_min_avg
    from ping_table X
)
select *
from xyz
where latest_row# = 1
;
```

For "last 10 minutes average" being "from 10 minutes ago until now" this is the query you are looking for:

```
with xyz as (
    select X.*,
        row_number() over (
            partition by ping_destination, ping_source
            order by ping_date desc
        ) as latest_row#,
        avg(ping_avg) over (
            partition by ping_destination, ping_source
        ) as the_10_min_avg
    from ping_table X
    where X.ping_date >= systimestamp - interval '10' minute
)
select *
from xyz
where latest_row# = 1
;
```

Comment: Works but I get rows that are older than 10 minutes.

Comment: You want rows not older than 10 minutes from "now"??

Comment: Ah, damn, you should've said that in your question in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ping_source, 
   first_value(ping_date) over (partition by ping_source order by ping_date desc),
  first_value(packet_loss) over (partition by ping_source order by ping_date desc)
 -- ... 
FROM data
CROSS JOIN
select avg(ping_avg) from data
where (sysdate - ping_date) * 24 * 60 < 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straight forward query based on the question.

Edited based on the sample output. For last 10 minutes from now, use systemtimestamp instead of i.latest_ping in the snippet "(i.latest_ping - interval '10' minute)". Use i.latest_ping for last 10 minutes from max_ping_time for that source-dest pair.

```
select 
    o.*, 
    (select avg(ping_avg) from ping_info a 
        where a.ping_source = i.ping_source
        and a.ping_dest = i.ping_dest
        and a.ping_date >= (systemtimestamp - interval '10' minute)
    ) last_10min_avg 
from ping_info o,
    (select ping_source, ping_dest, max(ping_date) latest_ping
    from ping_info
    group by ping_source, ping_dest) i
where o.ping_source = i.ping_source
and o.ping_dest = i.ping_dest
and o.ping_date = i.latest_ping;
```

Comment: Works but I get rows that are older than 10 minutes.